# Excluding inner tags from string using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text:

```
If there would be more <div>matches<div>in</div> string</div>, you will merge them to one
```

How do I make a JS regex that will produce the following text?

```
If there would be more <div>matches in string</div>, you will merge them to one
```

As you can see, the additional `<div>` tag has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple approach without using *Regex* by using `p` element of `html` and get its first div content as [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)(*exclude any html tags*) and affect it to `p`, finally get content but this time with [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```js
let text = 'If there would be more <div>mathces <div>in</div> string</div>, you will merge them to one';
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = text;
p.querySelector('div').innerText = p.querySelector('div').innerText;
console.log(p.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to [parseFromString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) into the more fluent [HTMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument) interface to solve this problem. You are not going to solve it well with regex.

```js
const htmlDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString("this <div>has <div>nested</div> divs</div>");

htmlDocument.body.childNodes; // NodeList(2): [ #text, div ]
```

From there, the algorithm depends on exactly what you want to do. Solving the problem *exactly* as you described to us isn't too tricky: recursively walk the DOM tree; remember whether you've seen a tag yet; if so, exclude the node and merge its children into the parent's children.

In code:

```js
const simpleExampleHtml = `<div>Hello, this is <p>a paragraph</p> and <div>some <div><div><div>very deeply</div></div> nested</div> divs</div> that should be eliminated</div>`

// Parse into an HTML document
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(exampleHtml, "text/html").body;

// Process a node, removing any tags that have already been seen
const processNode = (node, seenTags = []) => {
  // If this is a text node, return it
  if (node.nodeName === "#text") {
    return node.cloneNode()
  }
  // If this node has been seen, return its children
  if (seenTags.includes(node.tagName)) {
    // flatMap flattens, in case the same node is repeatedly nested
    // note that this is a newer JS feature and lacks IE11 support: https://caniuse.com/?search=flatMap
    return Array.from(node.childNodes).flatMap(child => processNode(child, seenTags))
  }
  // If this node has not been seen, process its children and return it
  const newChildren = Array.from(node.childNodes).flatMap(child => processNode(child, [...seenTags, node.tagName]))
  // Clone the node so we don't mutate the original
  const newNode = node.cloneNode()
  // We can't directly assign to node.childNodes - append every child instead
  newChildren.forEach(child => newNode.appendChild(child))
  return newNode
}

// resultBody is an HTML <body> Node with the desired result as its childNodes
const resultBody = processNode(doc);
const resultText = resultBody.innerHTML
// <div>Hello, this is <p>a paragraph</p> and some very deeply nested divs that should be eliminated</div>
```

**But make sure you know EXACTLY what you want to do!**

There's lots of potential complications you could face with data that's more complex than your example. Here are some examples where the simple approach may not give you the desired result.

```html
<!-- nodes where nested identical children are meaningful -->
<ul>
  <li>Nested list below</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Nested list item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- nested nodes with classes or IDs -->

<span>A span with <span class="some-class">nested spans <span id="DeeplyNested" class="another-class>with classes and IDs</span></span></span>

<!-- places where divs are essential to the layout -->

<div class="form-container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row"
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="text" name="password" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```